# Reactjs(Typescript) - Concatenate array in Select field

Tags: reactjs

I am making a request that returns an api array, however when performing the map, the results are not concatenated into just one select, duplicating the form fields.

```
const [systems, setSystems] = useState<SystemProps[]>([]);
useEffect(() => {
api.get(`/systems?&order=description`).then((response) => {
setSystems(response.data.data);
});
}, []);

return (
<div className="col-sm-4">
<label>Sistema</label>
{systems.map(system => (
<SelectForm
key="id"
name="system_id"
id="system_id"
placeholder="Selecione"
options={[{ value: system.id, label: system.description }]}
/>
))}
</div>
```

[look the duplicate select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMNjs.png)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not in English. Please visit pt.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Sorry, i adjusted the question

Comment: Please edit the title as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you’re looking for:

```
<label>Sistema</label>
<SelectForm
key="id"
name="system_id"
id="system_id"
placeholder="Selecione"
options={ systems.map(system => ({value: system.id, label: system.description })) }
/>
```

You want to `map` for the options, not the entire form.

Comment: Exactly that @jdaz, thank you very much for your help.